# phpmyadmin returns 403-Forbidden

Tags: php

When I enter `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` I get:

```
restarting apache2 (via systemctl): 
apache2.servicewarning: Unit file of apache2.service changed on disk, ‘systemct1 daemon-reload’ recommended.
job for apache2.service failed see systemctl status apache2.service and journalctl -xn for details
```

After performing `systemctl daemon-reload`, there is no error but I get

> 403-Forbidden

error on the browser when I tried to enter `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

Comment: Is [this question on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426479/cant-access-phpmyadmin-403-permission-error) relevant?

Comment: I hope it is.
As I am stuck while creating the web server and tried many things as well after that I am asking this question over here since I am a student still and I am stuck. and for this reason I have posted my question over here

Comment: Please post your `apache.conf` file.  There is something there that is probably not correct.  Check out [this posting for more information](http://askubuntu.com/questions/483297/why-do-i-always-get-a-403-error-with-phpmyadmin).